# Mapreduce carriage return

Tags: python, mapreduce, warc

I want to process CommonCrawl WARC files in MapReduce using the input format s3a.

The problem is that the carriage return char at the end of the input lines is removed and tab is put instead (as it is the default delimiter).

Why does this happen?

This is the code with which I start MapReduce

```
time yarn jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar \
  -D mapred.compress.map.output=true \
  -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
  -D mapred.job.name=cc \
  -D fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider \
  -files mapper.py \
  -archives wasbs://cluster@ccscsg.blob.core.windows.net/user/ubuntu/virtualenv/.venv2.zip#venv \
  -mapper mapper.py \
  -input s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-39/segments/1537267155413.17/warc/CC-MAIN-20180918130631-20180918150631-00000.warc.gz \
  -output /output_warc
```

mapper.py

```
#!./venv/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `-D mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator=$'\r'`. But this will add an `\r` to every line, even if there wasn't one in the input.

A MapReduce job expects as mapper output a pair  and the separator used to separate key and value in the output is set by (mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator` (the tab character is the default).

Btw., WARC files are not text files - there is binary payload (PDFs, images) and the HTML has no fixed content encoding. You may consider to use a WARC parsing library (e.g., [warcio](https://pypi.org/project/warcio/)) or simply use [cc-mrjob](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob) or [cc-pyspark](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark) to do the processing.

Comment: I added the warc library, but it throws an error saying that the WARC version is not correct because (in mapreduce) when the lines are read from stdin, WARC 1.0\r\n becomes WARC 1.0\t\n inside the mapper. The alternative I found is not to use s3a, but to use boto.

Comment: Hadoop streaming uses by default TextInputFormat which cannot be used because it modifies the input - unpacks it, removes `\r`, etc. As said, the WARC format is in principle a binary format and to be used in Hadoop streaming you would need to implement (in Java) an InputFormat, see the option `-inputFormat` in the [Hadoop streaming docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html). Not an easy taks and I would recommend to use one of the existing examples and libraries to process WARC files on Hadoop.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ahh ok, it's not my fault. In the end I used boto2 and then switched to boto3 for more stability